# Wpf Universal App Windows 10 VS 2015 How to handle multiple KeyDown events.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I am creating WPF universal app game "Pong" on VS 2015. 
Design:

```
<Page
x:Class="Pong.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Pong"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Canvas Name="MainCanavas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="640" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1024" Background="Black">
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="20" Fill="White" Name="LeftPad" Canvas.Top="{Binding YPosition}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="20" Fill="White" Name="RightPad" Canvas.Top="{Binding YPosition}" Canvas.Left="1005"></Rectangle>

    <Line X1="500" X2="500" Y2="630" Y1="15" StrokeThickness="5" StrokeDashArray="2"  Stroke="White"></Line>
    <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" Name="Ball" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="0.1" DataContext="{Binding Path=ball}" Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.48,0.587"></Ellipse>

    <TextBlock x:Name="LeftScore" Canvas.Left="374" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" Foreground="White" Canvas.Top="10" Height="134" Width="62" FontSize="96" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.481,0.499"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="RightScore" Canvas.Left="564" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" Foreground="White" Canvas.Top="10" Height="134" Width="62" FontSize="96" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.481,0.499"/>
</Canvas>
```

It's a 2 player game, so I wrote two paddle events, for left and right pads:

```
private void LeftPad_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Left pad events
        if (e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.W)
        {
            leftPad.YPosition -= padMoveBy;
        }

        if (e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.S)
        {
            leftPad.YPosition += padMoveBy;
        }
    }

    private void RightPad_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Right pad events
        if (e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Up)
        {
            rightPad.YPosition -= padMoveBy;
        }

        if (e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Down)
        {
            rightPad.YPosition += padMoveBy;
        }
    }
```

Main contructor:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += LeftPad_KeyDown;
        CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += RightPad_KeyDown;

        Ball.DataContext = ball;
        LeftPad.DataContext = leftPad;
        RightPad.DataContext = rightPad;
        LeftScore.DataContext = leftScore;
        RightScore.DataContext = rightScore;     

    }
```

When I run the program, I can move just one paddle at the time, even though I have two events.
Help would be nice...

Comment: Are you sure you are creating a **WPF** universal app game?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem or not, but I know that some keyboards only allow you to press a certain amount of keys at a time. For instance a player can't walk forward, strafe and jump at the same time. walking and jumping works, walking and strafing works, and strafing and jumping works, but you can't do all 3 at the same time. Something to do with the keyboard designs. Probably not your problem, but may have something to do with it.

Comment: Yes just WPF universal app game. I want to make players to be able to play on one keyboard, just like old times, P1: S, W; P2: Up, Down keys.

Comment: @CrushJelly WPF and UWP are two different technologies. In your case, it seems to be UWP. It's important to know that because solutions you find for WPF may not work for UWP

Comment: Ok, it's UWP then, just trying it for the very first time, but I ran into a trouble. I've tried many things, but it seems it doesn't work, and there is not that much examples about it.